# left outer join with custom ON condition sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using sequelize, DB as Postgres

my students table as ( id, name, dept_id ) columns.

my departments table as ( id, dname, hod) columns

My Association while looks like this

```
Student.hasOne(models.Department, {
    foreignKey: 'id',
    as : "role"
  });
```

I want to get a student with a particular id and his department details. By using sequelize I wrote a query like below

```
Student.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [{
        model: Department,
        as:"dept"
    }],
})
```

FYI with this includes option in findOne, it is generated a left outer join query as below

```
SELECT "Student"."id", "Student"."name", "Student"."dept_id", "dept"."id" AS "dept.id", "dept"."dname" AS "dept.dname", "dept"."hod" AS "dept.hod", FROM "students" AS "Student" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "departments" AS "dept" 
ON "Student"."id" = "dept"."id" 
WHERE "Student"."id" = 1 
LIMIT 1;
```

My expected Output should be

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "bod",
    dept_id: 4,
    dept: {
        id: 4,
        dname: "xyz",
        hod: "x"
    }
}
```

but I'm getting

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "bod",
    dept_id: 4,
    dept: {
        id: 1,
        dname: "abc",
        hod: "a"
    }
}
```

so how to I change ON condition to

```
ON "Student"."dept_id" = "dept"."id"
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Student.hasOne(models.Department, {
    foreignKey: 'dept_id', // fixed
    as : "role"
  });
```